# Angular Compilation error ng serve getting failed and throwing error while compiling an application

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new in angular and I have downloaded one of the git repo, and trying to run application and getting error as below.
If any one can help here.
Thanks in advance.
I have tried to remove packages and tried to re-install package again.
More over I tried to ***install npm install --legacy-peer-deps --force***

```
 ng serve     
0% compiling
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
10% building 3/4 modules 1 active {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
    at {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
    at {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:46:13)
    at processResource ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule ({{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at {{PATH_DIR}}\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Here is Angular.json file that may help.

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1, 
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "CompanyEmployees.Client.Oidc"
}
```

Here is Package.json file that may help you.
Package.json

```
{
  "name": "account-owner-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.38",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.10",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.10.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the angular version of the cloned repository and your local NodeJS version is mismatching in compatibility.

Angular `9.0.7` and NodeJS `18.13.0`

for Angular 9.1.x the compatible NodeJS version is ^10.13.0 || ^12.11.0

You can either downgrade the Node version or use NVM to change the Node version for this folder.

For future references [Angular-Versions](https://angular.io/guide/versions) :)

Comment: I tried as you suggested but getting version error.
ng serve       
Node.js version v10.18.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.


ng serve
Node.js version v12.11.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Comment: Run `npm i --f` in your project folder and check the angular version in your project folder by running `ng version` if it is same as the angular cli version in your package.json file, we are good to go for build. else we can install the required angular version by `npm install @angular/cli@"your package.json angular/cli version"` for your case `npm install @angular/cli@9.0.1`. now we have compatible node and angular versions. try running ng serve now **do not install this angular version globally**. hope this resolves the issue. feel free to reach out

Answer (score 0):

Look like node modules are not installed as required

First remove node modules folder and remove package-lock.json

After removing both just use command `npm i --force`

Hope this helps.